# Se puede hacer subqueries en Ms Access?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2010

Buenas tardes tengo una duda por lo regular yo trabajo con MySQL pero hoy un compañero me pregunto si podia hacer una consulta en su tabla de Access, es decir me pidio una guía, yo genere la siguiente consulta en MySQL:

```
SELECT c.FACULTAD,
       count(CASE WHEN c.modalidad LIKE 'VIRTUAL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS VIRTUAL,
       count(CASE WHEN c.modalidad LIKE 'PRESENCIAL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
          AS PRESENCIAL
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.FACULTAD,
                        p.MATERIA,
                        p.MODALIDAD                 
                FROM prueba p
        GROUP BY p.FACULTAD, p.MATERIA, p.MODALIDAD) c
GROUP BY c.FACULTAD
```

pero el me dice que en Access no se ejecuta. Ustedes saben si se puede ejecutar este tipo de consultas en access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, se pueden hacer subqueries en Access, acabo de probar ésta y funciona:

```
SELECT Max(c1.Suma) AS MáxDeSuma
  FROM (
    SELECT provincias.autonomia, Sum(provincias.poblacion) AS Suma
      FROM provincias
      GROUP BY provincias.autonomia
  )  AS c1;
```

Lo que no existe es el `CASE WHEN`. El `GROUP BY` de la subconsulta no es necesario que lo pongas, pues ya usas un `DISTINCT` y no calculas ningún total que lo requiera.

Como alternativa a tu `CASE WHEN` puedes usar la función `IIf`:

```
SELECT IIf([Suma]>1000000,"Muy poblada","Poco poblada") AS Valoración,
  c1.autonomia
  FROM (
    SELECT provincias.autonomia, Sum(provincias.poblacion) AS Suma
      FROM provincias
      GROUP BY provincias.autonomia
  )  AS c1;
```

Comment: muchas gracias! ya le hago el cambio y le paso a la persona que lo requiere